# 2 shopping cart application in one server, localhost

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have developed 2 shopping cart application in my localhost.Lets say sc1 and sc2.I opened those 2 sites in two different tabs of one particular browerser.

I added 3 items of sc1 in cart-1.But when i m trying to add any item of sc2 in cart-2,it gives that item along with those items in the cart-1 of sc1.

I started session(session_start();) in index.php of both the application.
How to solve the problem.I got to know using session.cookie_path will solve.I tried but it wud not solve my proble.Is there any extra step to follow or any extra function to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`session_name("application name")`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) before `session_start()`. This sets the name of the cookie used to identify the session (default is "PHPSESSID").

Use a different name for each application.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the browser in new session? For IE => Alt-key, File, New session....

However, for your application you can maybe better check the session_id...when session_id is correct, then you may add a item to the cart, else leave.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same session names on both installs.
Change the session name on a per install basis and it'll be fine.

For example if you have a session called cart on both then anything you add to sc1 will appear in sc2 but the item will be different because the item id stored in the session will match a different ID in the different database. Which is exactly what you're seeing.

The best solution is to store a session name in the DB settings table and then use that to name the session on a per site basis and it then allows you to customise it on a per site basis. Or you could use a define in the config.s